# How to find Regex for dynamically generated id's?

Tags: regex, jmeter

For some id, say, @@@@0584060878.1322216046@@@ , I got my regular expression as 
(.+?)&

Now, I have a form for which a dynamically generated id is as follows:

```
1. id= "form-aMzlSOPDQQEmKXeCq-I6HEMTwPITGt5TtxcgcVRkoPA"

2. id = "form-qHkkSwdhlzNLlnnEa2XFpKbFOPdVax-up51VUWOqv9k"
```

What can be used as regex for these kind of generated ids? I need to use that particular regex in Jmeter.

Comment: stackoverflow is _not_ a regex library. I suggest attempting to put together a regex first - learning enough to do it will take you an hour. If someone was kind enough to attemp an answer, you need to at least tell us which part of the string you want to retrieve in order to give a better chance of an accurate answer - ie, what is the expected output?

Comment: This actually does not answer Gusdor's question, I think he is asking if the dash character between the two parts after 'form-' is a separator. If your id is in two parts or not.

Answer (score 3):

regex is:

`form-[0-9a-zA-Z\-]{43}`

which means: **form** succeeded with **-** succeeded with **43 characters** *(either (capital) letters, dash or numbers)*

You could also write the regex a little shorter as:

`form-[\w\-]{43}`

but this notation also accepts underscore in any of the 43 characters)

Answer (score 3):

First of all asking an exact regex doesn't make sense. 
You need to consider what you need to match and how strict you want to be.

Assuming you need to match the full id's with no specific character or length requirements.
Following simple regex would match both id's you provided.

`form-.+-.+`